# How to get Power saving mode in UWP Apps?

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, windows-phone

I am trying to get the power saving mode in UWP apps and I find the PowerManager class in **Windows​.Phone​.System​.Power.dll** and I am not able to reference it in UWP apps.. is there any other way to check the power saver mode is enabled? and my target device is windows 10 tablet as of now.. if there's way to reference **Windows​.Phone​.System​.Power.dll** in the Universal Windows project please let me know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a UWP app you should use Windows.System.Power.PowerManager (i.e. not from the phone namespace, which is for WP 8.1 apps):
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.power.powermanager

Thanks - Stefan Wick

Windows Developer Platform